# Trying to get Datastax Spark Master to listen on public IP

Tags: apache-spark, datastax

I want to submit Spark jobs with my Java client and Spark Master running on different hosts.
I've tried setting SPARK_MASTER_IP and SPARK_LOCAL_IP in spark-env.sh to the public IP but the sparkMaster is always bound to 127.0.0.1.
How can I bind the Spark Master to my public IP?

**Update 14/1/15:**
You can view my spark-env.sh file [in pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jEgxUSuq)

ifconfig (on spark master) output:

```
ens32: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 10.76.28.117  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 10.76.29.255
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe87:d94  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:50:56:87:0d:94  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 4392194  bytes 1030005387 (982.2 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2828  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 556316  bytes 114056485 (108.7 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 810654  bytes 602987986 (575.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 810654  bytes 602987986 (575.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Could you provide your "ifconfig" output in the original question please and share your /etc/dse/spark/spark-env.sh also? iirc unless you specify the IP it should listen on all interface for the default port on 7080 for the master. Thanks

Comment: @markc I updated the question with the details

Comment: ok thanks so have you tried binding it to the 10.76.28.117 address?

Comment: @markc You can see in the spark-env file that I've tried to bind to the hostname "dse-all-in-one". I might be doing this wrong. How do you recommend binding to 10.76.28.117?

Comment: so you are using the hostname, but does this resolve to the right IP on the machine? Whats the contents of your /etc/hosts file and what does the command 'nslookup dse-all-in-one' return?

Comment: The hostname is resolved correctly

Comment: Could you try putting the IP instead of the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

I had my rpc_address in cassandra.yaml set to "0.0.0.0". After changing it to the real IP address of the node it worked.